# not able to create VC++ project, with VS11

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I just installed VS11 professional version on windows 8 consumer preview OS.

I tried to create a win32 console app, wizard fails with following error:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\VCWizards\default.vcxproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.vcxproj) is not supported by this version of the application. 

To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project.
OK
```

Not sure what i'm missing. Anyone here can help me? 
[image: This is the screenshot during error]

Comment: You have professional version, so can't you contact tech support about that?

Comment: I thought i might get answer on stackoverflow very fast than from microsoft's tech support. Actually it happened like that before, back in 2009 to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find the answer. Re-installation of VS11 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what fixed it for me, check your User environment variables for VCHOME, VCINSTALLDIR and vsinstalldir.

Change

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
```

to

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\
```

Or

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\
```

depending VS 2012 or 2013.

Comment: This from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/279c09f3-5391-49c9-ac75-d6f6b921bd0f/visual-c-project-system-package-package-did-not-load-correctly?forum=vssetup

Comment: that was me :) btw you can just delete those vars it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Run VS2011 first and than drag and drop project file in it. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come to this thread with the same problem but for VS2015: installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 fixed the problem for me.