# Visual Studio 2012 error: Package 'Visual C++ package' failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vspackage

When I'm trying to open any solutions that worked fine before in Visual Studio 2012, the error "Package 'Visual C++ package' failed to load" keeps showing up. And the solution can't be opened.

I'm not sure what's wrong with my Visual Studio 2012 installation.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114464/visual-studio-2015-community-visual-c-project-system-package-error

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> 1. click the TOOLS--->VISUAL STUDIO COMMAND PROMPT   to open the command window
> 2. input the command "devenv /Setup"
> 3. open the visual studio 2012 again, it will works.

Source: http://happyivyli.blogspot.com/2013/07/visual-c-package-failed-to-load.html

Comment: I was just about to reinstall VS2012, great find!

Comment: after typing devenv /Setup it just sits there no error no nothing

Comment: This worked for me despite showing an error message ("not authorized" or something).  Restarted Visual Studio afterward, and then it worked.

Comment: For anyone like me who can't find the VS Command Prompt in VS2013, it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts`

Answer (score 7):

**Running command prompt from inside Visual Studio.**

For easier access, you can add the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt or any other command prompt to the Tools menu on Visual Studio, by adding it to the external tools list. This is how you can accomplish that:

1. Open Visual Studio.
2. Select the **Tools** menu and choose **External Tools**...
3. On the **External Tools** dialog box, choose the **Add** button. A new entry appears.
4. Enter a **Title** for your new menu item such as **Command Prompt**.
5. In the **Command** field, specify the file you want to launch such as **%comspec%** or **C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe**.
6. In the **Arguments** field, specify where to find the specific command prompt you want to use such as **/k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"** (this will launch the Developer Command Prompt installed with Visual Studio 2015). This value needs to be changed according to your Visual Studio version and installation location.
7. Choose a value for the **Initial directory** field such as **Project Directory**.
8. Choose the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
   After that, the new menu item is added and you can access the command prompt from the Tools menu.

Then:

1. **Right-click** the Visual Studio icon
2. Choose **Run As Administrator**
3. Click the menu *TOOLS* → *Command Prompt** to open the command window
4. Input the command **"devenv /Setup"**
5. Open Visual Studio again, and it will work.

Comment: How will this help fix the problem "Package 'Visual C++ package' failed to load"?

Comment: @Peter, I don't know abou you for it helped me with similar problem.

Answer (score 4):

None of the solutions I found around, including those listed here, seemed to help. What did work was going in the software install/uninstall management, right clicking on Visual Studio and choosing "change" (that's where you would normally uninstall something from).

That should pop up the Visual Studio package manager, and from there you can choose repair.

In my case, looking at the systems backlog and restore points, it seems it was one of the Visual C++ redistributables, possibly installed by some game, that compromised the environment.

This is on Windows 8.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me on VS2013.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly same fix as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21266545/990618

Check your User environment variables for VCHOME, VCINSTALLDIR and vsinstalldir.

Change

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
```

to

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\
```

Or

```
X:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\
```

depending VS 2012 or 2013.