# How to fix VS2015 Package 'VisualBasicPackage' failed to load?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have projects in a solution going from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2015 with Update 1.  I just installed VS2015 with update 1 on a Windows 7 Continuous Integration build server and I'm getting the following errors. I've been digging around on the Internet for a couple days now with no leads on how to fix this. I've read similar posts on here that relate to other "packages" not being loaded but the recommended fixes haven't worked for this. I've uninstalled and reinstalled vs2015 a few times and still get the same errors. Any thoughts or ideas on how to fix?

```
Package 'VisualBasicPackage' failed to load.
C:\Workspaces\AHLTA\Current\Product\Production\Shared\Security\Security.vbproj : error  : The application for the project is not installed.

Package 'VisualBasicPackage' failed to load.
C:\Workspaces\AHLTA\Current\Product\Production\Shared\Shared\Shared.vbproj : error  : Project 'Shared' could not be opened because the Visual Basic 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.

Package 'CSharpPackage' failed to load.
C:\Workspaces\AHLTA\Current\Product\production\DataLayer\Dmdc\Immunizations.Messaging\Immunizations.Messaging.csproj : error  : Project 'Immunizations.Messaging' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. Please re-install Visual Studio.
```

UPDATE #1: I think I may have resolved this myself just now.
I found this post and tried the suggestion, now the build seems to be compiling correctly with no errors.
[vs2012 error: package 'visual c++ package' failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819613/vs2012-error-package-visual-c-package-failed-to-load)

Answer (score 0):

The information on the following link seems to have solved the problem I'm having. http://happyivyli.blogspot.com/2013/07/visual-c-package-failed-to-load.html