# Error - This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Python package for VS.NET 2013 from the VS itself. After that i could not open any C++ Project. I got this Error Message:

[image]

**Full Text:**

Unsupported

This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects.vcxproj The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.

```
 - PROJECT_NAME, "C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\xx\PROJECT_NAME.vcxproj"
```

Non-functional changes required

Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - ImageRegistrationEngine, "C:\xx\xx\xx\xx\PROJECT_NAME.sln"

**EDIT:**

The project was created on the same machine using the exactly same version of VS.NET..

BTW, I still can open C# projects but not C++ ones.

Comment: Which version of VS were the projects created for?  This kind of message is quite common when you try to mix versions of VS projects on the same machine.  It is possible for versions to coexist (I have 3 versions on my machine), but you have to be disciplined and careful, particularly with environment variables.  Probably best to use different machines or use Virtual Machines.

Comment: The same of the visual studio version. It is actually the same version and the same machine.. I was able to open it 5 minutes ago

Comment: Not that then.  What do you mean by  "installed Python ... from the VS itself"?  Did you recompile Python?

Comment: I wanted to try a python code on my machine. So I opened VS and create new Python project. VS told me that I do not have the package of Python and asked me if I want to download it. I did. Then I created python project and write my code then tried to run it. VS told me again that I need Python interpreter and asked me if I want to download it. I did. Python worked.. C++ not working anymore!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The accepted answer in this question solved my problem.

[vs2012 error: package 'visual c++ package' failed to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819613/vs2012-error-package-visual-c-package-failed-to-load)

I opened **Developer Command Prompt for VS2013** and write `devenv /Setup` (while VS is closed). Then, I started VS again and everything was alright.

Comment: This solved the problem, remember to use 'run as Admin...' to open Developer Command Prompt.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well.  I forgot I installed "Visual Studio Installer Projects" when I built my application on a different machine.  My new machine didn't have it, and installing it didn't fix the issue.  Had to run the command above for it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Opened Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 in administrator mode and executed devenv /Setup (while VS is closed).
Then VS started working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced same problem while loading .net core projects. Solution was for me is below

1. Reset all for Vs 2015 /VS2017 settings in Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings.
2. try to run the VS updates and restart VS aftet that.
3. open vs in admin mode.