# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 & VS 2015 Express couldn't load .vcxproj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I couldn't open and create Win32 Project in VS 2015 Update 3 and Express. I've received notification that "The 'Visual C++ Project System Package' package did not load correctly".  I have tried:
1) Repair install VS
2) Uninstall + Reinstall VS
3) Typing in command prompt devenv.exe /resetskippkgs

Nothing works. Please help

Comment: Possibly an answer/solution.  Several have upvoted as helpful, but it was not formally accepted as an answer by the asker: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37646937/2486496

Comment: It doesn't work. I've recived "Those Projects are not Supported".

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  You wouldn't receive that error when performing a `rmdir` from the command line.

Comment: Is your Operating system a non-English one.

Comment: The error occurred when I re-opened the project. Yes, my system is a non-English .