# Not able to create VC++ project Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am unable to create a VC++ project in VS2015 Community. When I attempt to do so, I get two messages starting with, 'The "Visual Studio C++ Project System Package" did not load correctly.' Then this fatal message appears: [image]

I also have VS2005 Professional installed on my machine; I need the two for different projects.

This seemed similar to [not able to create VC++ project, with VS11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039900/not-able-to-create-vc-project-with-vs11) so I created a batch file that sets those env vars and then calls devenv.exe for VS2015. Still got the same error messages.

[Visual Studio 2015 (community)- cannot create new project c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333686/visual-studio-2015-community-cannot-create-new-project-c) suggests an incompatibility between two versions and to delete an old directory. But as I need both versions, that does not seem to be a good solution either (and suggestion didn't appear to help that OP).

As final data points, Intel Visual Fortran 2017 is installed and integrated with VS2015, and I note that a resulting VFPROJ file is in the pre-VS2010 format - .vcproj format with <VisualStudioProject> being an element.

At any rate, I cannot create a new project inside VS2015 for C++ and would appreciate your help towards a solution.

Comment: Maybe you don't have the c++ compiler installed. If that is not the case maybe you want to reinstall Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thanks, C++ was originally installed.

Answer (score 0):

I chose Repair for on VS2015 under Control Panel - Programs and Features and I am now able to create a C++ project. I will continue testing by creating a nother Fortran project and if it causes the problem to recur I will repost.